# Procmail not bouncing emails

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, email-bounces, procmail

I have a catch-all email address for my domain, however I want to block certain addresses from receiving mail. Before, I was doing it like this:

```
:0
* ^(X-Original-To): username@example.com
/dev/null
```

This works fine, however, the email is silently disregarded. I want a bounce mail to be sent back to the sender so that they know that it's being rejected. I used similar code to [this](https://serverfault.com/a/775166) answer:

```
:0
* ^(X-Original-To): username@example.com
{ EXITCODE=67 HOST= }
```

However, now the emails are being delivered and no bounce mail is being sent.

Comment: Really, with a typo in `EXITCODE`? How do you invoke Procmail  exactly, which MTA etc? Do you have an example of Procmail's delivery log?

Comment: Is this recipe in your personal `.procmailrc` or in `/etc/procmailrc`?

Comment: @tripleee I have no idea how that typo got in there. It's fine in the file, so I must have hit a key or something after I pasted it in here. Also, this recipe is in the user's `.procmailrc` file.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem? If so, please consider an [edit] to provide more details, or posting an answer of your own explaining how you solved it. In its current form, this is unlikely to help future visitors, and should simply be closed as unreproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious typo in your attempt, your example works if I put the recipe in my personal `.procmailrc`.

Here's a quick demo on Ubuntu in a fresh Docker container where I installed Postfix, Procmail, and Netcat, and created a user account for myself:

```
tripleee@0934b6a257c9:~$ cat >.procmailrc
LOGFILE=/tmp/procmail.log

:0
* ^(X-Original-To): username@example.com
{ EXITCODE=67 HOST= }
^D
tripleee@0934b6a257c9:~$ nc localhost 25
220 0934b6a257c9 ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo localhost
250-0934b6a257c9
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
mail from:<tripleee>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:<tripleee>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
X-Original-To: username@example.com
Subject: first

who's on first
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 608C329A304
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
^C
tripleee@0934b6a257c9:~$ cat /tmp/procmail.log 
From tripleee@0934b6a257c9  Fri Mar  4 11:50:59 2022
 Subject: first
  Folder:                                     0
From MAILER-DAEMON  Fri Mar  4 11:50:59 2022
 Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
  Folder: /var/mail/tripleee                           2267
```

However, the same recipe in `/etc/procmailrc` causes the message to be delivered anyway; basically, `HOST=` says skip the *current* recipe file, but in `/etc/procmailrc`, that means stop reading this file and proceed to deliver to the user.

I can only speculate that that is the actual problem you are experiencing. If you have more details, please edit your question to provide them.

As an aside, the parentheses are superfluous, and the dot should be escaped.

```
:0
* ^X-Original-To: username@example\.com
{ EXITCODE=67 HOST= }
```

If you enable verbose logging with `VERBOSE=yes` you'll see that Procmail actually assigns `HOST=}` which is not really what I would expect, but it works (as long as your `HOST` isn't really named `}`!)

Notice also how the log file shows the incoming message being discarded, and then a bounce message being delivered to me (as I was the sender as well as the recipient). However, the generated bounce message includes text which (obscurely) reveals that the recipient address actually does exist after all:

```
<tripleee@0934b6a257c9> (expanded from <tripleee>): user unknown
```

You probably have to be fairly intimately familiar with Postfix bounce messages to understand exactly what this means; it basically says that it expanded `tripleee` to a fully expanded email address with the domain name included, and then delivering to that produced the error message to the right of the colon.  (For better or for worse, Sendmail's bounce messages are more obscure still; but the real pro of unintelligible error messages, as always, is Microsoft.)

Comment: And sorry that the earlier answer was slightly imprecise in this detail; I have updated it now.

Comment: Very explanatory answer, however it's on my `.procmailrc` file so I don't think that it applies to me. Perhaps I need to try to enable logging as you have it here and see what shows up.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://www.iki.fi/era/mail/procmail-debug.html

Comment: ... and `sendmail -v` if you are not comfortable speaking raw SMTP to the mail server yourself.